# How to retrieve the dynamic reactive form values which is submitted back to UI?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I used reactive forms in angular 7 to create the form dynamically. I am able to generate the form and get the values in a proper format and able to submit properly. My problem is, I need to retrieve those values back in the UI on renewing the form. In short, i need to repopulate those dynamic form values in UI when renewing the form.

i am able to add the form dynamically on click of 'Add' button. and able to submit the form. I have used ngModel for two way data binding for repopulating it in UI.

I want the submitted form values to repopulate in UI when renewing.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znAnX.png)

Comment: I have followed this tutorial implementation - https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-build-nested-model-driven-forms-in-angular-2

Comment: Why are you using ngModel when you have a form? You can get and set the values of your form directly in typescript. Here is an article how to solve that: https://medium.com/aubergine-solutions/add-push-and-remove-form-fields-dynamically-to-formarray-with-reactive-forms-in-angular-acf61b4a2afe

Comment: i have an add button .. on click of which it generates the form. SO i have used ngModel fro repopulating

Comment: If I understand you right you have a dynamic array of form groups. Here you can use a form array as described in the medium tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the form builder for that:

```
save(model: Customer) {
     // call API to save customer
     console.log(model);
     // repopulate the form
    this.myForm = this._fb.group({
            name: [model.name, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)]],
            addresses: this._fb.array([
                this.initAddress(model.address),
            ])
        });
}
```

Comment: this works when i have simple form. But i have a dynamic form which gets generated on click of add button.

Comment: @Revathi Can you post the code so we can understand what are you trying to do?